# Sharepoint List New Form Display

Tags: list

I have a more theoretical question. I have a made a column in SharePoint using the select type to say Success, Processing and Failed. I want the list to store the values as numbers such as Success=1, processing=2 and fail=3. Is this possible?

I have a solution which involves calculated column that uses IF statements, but it is not a very feasible option when I have 20-30 columns. I am trying to reduce the number of columns required to a minimum.

I have looked through the New Form aspx code but am not able to find the location to change the code to customize the webpart.

I need a solution that doesn't involve InfoPaths.I am able to perform custom coding if required but I would like to avoid that.

Thanks

Comment: do you mean that you want to display the status in the form of numbers like 1.2.3 and not wordings right

Comment: I want the form to show the words. but I want the list to show the numbers. Basically I need the Forms to Display the words, but the list to show numbers. The list is a data source for a dashboard so I need to use KPIs to evaluate the values.

Comment: all the list form should use the text values? so basically while editing the selection combo box should display the textual values?

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Are you on SP2010 or SP2013/Online ?? The traditional way of doing it is to put the number in the value: (1) Success, (2) Processing, (3) Fail. In SP2013 onwards you can use [CSR (Client Side Rendering)](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013).

Comment: Second question: Do you **only** want it displayed in a View?? You can use [this trickery](http://viewmaster365.com/#/How) in both 2010 en 2013/Online

Comment: I am Using SP2013 on-premises. I have not tried this client side rendering. Will try that. The goal is to have the person filling out the form see Success, Processing, Fail as the options, and the sharepoint list to read the options as 1,2,3.

Comment: Then CSR is the way to go for you. CSR is all about presenting information in the back-end differently to the end-user on Forms, Views etc.. Only use the magical stuff I mentioned (and only works in Views) when you can't use CSR.

Answer (score 1):

You could always create a extra calculated column. Take a look at my example, "Choice" are the column name. Replace it to your column name.

```
=IF([Choice]="Success","1",(IF([Choice]="Processing","2",(IF([Choice]="Failed","3"))))
```

This is the result:
[image][image]

Comment: Yes I have actually done this method, but the method will become very messy when I have 20 to 30 fields. I am trying to limit the number of columns required to a min to create data redundancy. Thank you for this solution though.

Comment: You left that detail out in your question. With that many fields, this can easily be solved with InfoPath  as you can bind a single datasource to multiple fields, and/or set the choice fields to have a internal value (1,2,3) while displaying a text value.. InfoPath is all out of bounds for this?

Comment: Sorry for leaving out that detail. Like I said in my post, Using Infopath is not an option here. I am looking for a method that can either use visual basic or workflows to do the job.

Comment: I don't think that you can create a custom choice column using code that actually stores a internal value but displays something else.. That would be a lookup column but you can't have that many columns either.. If you go with a workflow, you would still need an additional column for every field.. and that would be a large workflow, including checking 30 fields and then set another 3 fields based on the value..

Comment: I agree. I have tried to do it with a workflow, where the workflow checks the field value in the column and replaces that value with a number that didn't yield the proper results. So you don't believe there is a way to make a custom list type to do what I want?